# Samsung 20 delete phone contact

Tags: samsung

Brand new samsung 20 will not allow me to delete a contact without phone # and stays on recently added and home screen

Comment: If your device is connected to your Google account and the contact is synced to the cloud you may succeed to delete it via [Google Contacts web site](https://contacts.google.com).

Answer (score 0):

quite a strange thing, considering the fact that your phone is new.
well, there are basic steps to deleting contacts:

1. From a Home screen, swipe up from the center of the display to access the apps screen.
2. Tap Contacts Contacts icon.
3. Select the desired contact.
4. Tap the Menu icon Menu icon (upper-right).
5. Tap Delete.
6. Tap Delete to confirm.

maybe if the phone is required for content to be deleted, you could try add some random number just to refresh the contact? vfwbe then you will manage to delete it...